# save substring as a bounded string in ada

Tags: string, substring, ada

I have got following code:

```
Put_Line(Source_String (Source_String'First + Start-1..Source_String'First + Stop-2));
```

It works correctly, but I want to use it as a bounded string.

```
   String1: String(1..50);
```

If I use

```
   String1:= Source_String (Source_String'First + Start-1..Source_String'First + Stop-2)
```

But this block of code doesn't work. I can't use substring as a String. Compile doesn't output any errors, but also doesn't work
P.S. When I use Put_Line only, my program works correctly

Comment: Please don't post questions that tell us that something "doesn't work".  Tell us what actually happened.  I am at a loss to understand why people ask us for help and then hide important information from us.

Comment: Sorry, this is a first time when I am asking a question. Try to fix it

Comment: See also [*A.4.3 Fixed-Length String Handling*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-3.html).

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a misconception here : `String1: String(1..50);` doesn't declare a bounded string but a fixed string. Realising that, it's easy to see why the assignment usually "doesn't work" ... the slice of Source_String must be exactly 50 characters long or the assignment will give a constraint error.

One solution is to use a Bounded String, but that may not be necessary here, so I'm going to suggest a simpler approach.

Think about the program, and structure it so that the runtime values of `Source_String`, `Start` and `Stop` are all known before the declaration of `String1`. One tool you can use is the "declare block" - this allows declarations to be kept local to their point of use, which is good programming practice... Later on, when you're refactoring, these make great candidates for abstracting out into procedures.

Now you can move the assignment into the declaration, as an initialiser, and the string takes its length from the initialisation. The fact that its length is unknown until runtime doesn't matter, you can find the length from its attributes.

You can move quite a lot into the declarations, and if you don't intend to modify the contents another good practice is to make the declarations constant. So the code might look like:

```
Start := ...
declare
   Source_String : constant String := Read_Line(File);
   Stop  : constant Natural := Second_Space(Source_String);
   String1 : constant String := Source_String (Source_String'First + Start-1
                                .. Source_String'First + Stop-2);
begin
   -- process String1
end; -- String1 goes out of scope here.
```